# Most efficient filing

Tags: php

The situation is that i have to fill rooms with a *x* number of persons.
For this example lets use:

```
$persons = 7;
```

And i got a array with:

```
$differentRoom = array(
    'Room 1' => 1, //This room fits 1 person
    'Room 2' => 2, //This room fits 2 persons
    'Room 3' => 3, //This room fits 3 persons
);
```

Now i want that PHP makes combinations that is exactly 7 in the shortest way. The result have to be, you need : 'Room3' 'Room 3' 'Room 1'

in another example i have

```
$persons = 15;
```

And a array with

```
$differentRooms = array(
    'Room 1' => 4, // This room fits x persons
    'Room 2' => 7,
);
```

This time a combination can't be exactly 15.
In this situation the result have to be a combination that is more then 15.
In this case it would be 16. 16 is nearest to 10, and the result have to be. You need : 'Room 2''Room 2' 'Room 1'

How can i do this?

Comment: Tricky question. In the general case, I'm willing to bet that this is NP-hard. This is actually a math question. You'll probably get better answers to this question over [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sounds like the bin packing problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: In your second example `Room 1`+`Room 1`+`Room 2` would be exactly 10. What takes precedence: a lower number of rooms or an exact fit? (In your first example R2+R2+R3 would also be valid.)

Comment: Are there any other rules? F.ex. by "most efficient", you mean the solution, which consist of the least number of rooms?

Comment: have you heard of greedy algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need greedy algorithm. This one should work. I've written it now

```
$differentRoom = array(
'Room 1' => 4, 
'Room 2' => 7 
);

$persons = 15;
arsort($differentRoom);

$min_rooms_capacity = min($differentRoom);


while($persons>=$min_rooms_capacity)
{
  $tmp = $differentRoom;
  $toSubstract = 0;
  do
  {
    $toSubstract = array_shift($tmp);
  }
  while($toSubstract>$persons);
  echo $toSubstract.',';
  $persons-=$toSubstract;
}
```

it can be obviosly improved but it should give you the advice how to handle such situations. I don't know the name of algorithm in English but in Polish the direct translation would be "backpack problem"

More about greedy algorithms on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The problem is NP-hard and a variant of the knapsack problem with repetition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem for some more info on the subject).

The notable modification is, instead of trying to get the largest weight in as possible, you're trying to get a weight as close as possible to a certain value. This can be done by changing the weight function.

The best solution for it is dynamic programming, which you may want to look into. This, however, is more of an algorithm/CSci question, so it'd be better to post it on the maths/programming stackexchange question boards.